# How to open static web page on remote machine trough file:// protocol

Tags: ssh, firefox, browser, filesystems, remote

On a remote computer, a code documentation (static html pages) is located at `/path/to/docs`.
To access it, the recommended way is to start NoMachine, get a virtual desktop, start the web browser (firefox) and open `file:///path/to/docs`.

I would like to know if it's possible to open theses files on my local web browser trough ssh, proxy or whatever.

E.g `file://///remote_adress/path/to/docs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to simply insert the remote machine's address and view their files.

However, you do have some options that will allow you to achieve the desired result.

## Setup a Webserver *(preferred)*

You could install a webserver on the remote machine, and configure it to serve up the pages you're after. This would be the most sensible approach, and will result in your browser making HTTP requests to retrieve the files.

- If you're on Windows, then you may be able to use [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services).
- You could use [Nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) or [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) on most (all?) platforms - Windows, Linux, OSX

For this approach, you'd use a standard URL, e.g:

```
http://remote_host/index.html
```

This would also allow you to make use of dynamic content, through [server-side scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting).

If you aren't able to listen on port 80 / 443 (because you aren't root), then you can still listen on a non-privileged port (i.e: greater than `1024`)... for example [`8080`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers), which is a common alternative.

## Mount Remote Filesystem

This approach will depend entirely on what operating system you're using.

I'm not familiar with macOS, so haven't discussed it.

#### Windows

If you're using Windows, then you will need to "*share*" the folder on the remote machine before you can access it locally. There are many guides on how to do this.

Once you've shared the directory, you can use the following URL:

```
file://////remote_host/share_name/index.htm
```

You could also map (mount) the shared directory locally, for example as your `X:` drive (note the tripple slash):

```
file:///X:/index.htm
```

#### Linux / *nix

You have a number of options for mounting the remote directory locally ([NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS), [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)), etc...). Once mounted, you can use the same approach as any other file accessible in your [VFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system).

For example, if you run `sshfs user@remote_host:/path/to/files /mnt/remote`, then the following will work:

```
file:///mnt/remote/index.html
```

Comment: Without elevated privileges no webserver, so mounting the filesystem is the right suggestion.

Comment: You can run a web server on a non-privileged port (i.e >1024)

Answer (score 1):

This is generally *not* possible. The `file:` protocol can only be used with things that [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) (or its cross-platform equivalents) can deal with. I have never seen anything support the "host" part of the URL.

On Windows, this also includes file shares. URL would look like this:

```
file://///server/share/My%20file.html
```

On Linux (and probably most UNIX-y systems) you’d need to have it accessible somewhere in the VFS tree. You could accomplish this by *mounting* the remote file system locally using NFS, Samba, sshfs, ‌…. Of course this means the remote file system must be accessible using one of these protocols, usually requiring some setup on the remote system.

Depending on your OS and browser, you may be able to use other VFSs like KIO (KDE), GIO (Gnome) or others.

Comment: Are all of the slashes required? Both 2x (as per my answer) and 6x (as per yours) seem to work here.

Comment: It’s actually 5. And no, two slashes don’t work for me in Firefox, I just get a blank page. It works in Edge though.

Comment: So it is!... It seems that 5 or 6 work for me (in Firefox too). Interesting, thanks...